# sequelize-typescript error when passing object to create

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

While using the `sequelize-typescript npm`
When trying to invoke the `Street.create(obj)` I get an error:

> Argument of type 'plainObject' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'Optional<Street, NullishPropertiesOf>'.   Type 'plainObject'
> is missing the following properties from type 'Omit<Street,
> NullishPropertiesOf>': sequelize, destroy, restore, update,
> and 39 more

This is the model:

```
import { Table, Model, Column, PrimaryKey } from 'sequelize-typescript';


@Table({ timestamps: false, tableName: 'street' })
class Street extends Model<Street> {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column
    street_id: string;

    @Column
    location_id: string;

    @Column
    location_symbol: string;

    @Column
    street_name: string;

    @Column
    street_synonym: string;

    @Column
    street_symbol: string;

    @Column
    updated: Date;
}

export default Street;
```

this is the call

```
 Street.create({
                location_id: 'string',
                location_symbol: 'string',
                street_name: 'string',
                street_synonym: 'string',
                street_id: 'string',
                street_symbol: 'string',
                updated: new Date(),
            });
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are using sequelize v6.

Just remove generic `<Street>` and it will work. You don't need it anymore.

```
import { Table, Model, Column, PrimaryKey } from 'sequelize-typescript';


@Table({ timestamps: false, tableName: 'street' })
class Street extends Model {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column
    street_id: string;

    @Column
    location_id: string;

    @Column
    location_symbol: string;

    @Column
    street_name: string;

    @Column
    street_synonym: string;

    @Column
    street_symbol: string;

    @Column
    updated: Date;
}

export default Street;
```

Comment: This removes any typechecking on the call to `create` or `bulkCreate`. I'd recommend the other answer to avoid breaking the type system.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create an interface that the model uses

F.x.:

```
import { Table, Model, Column, PrimaryKey } from 'sequelize-typescript';

interface IStreet {
    street_id: string;
    location_id: string;
    location_symbol: string;
    street_name: string;
    street_synonym: string;
    street_symbol: string;
    updated: Date;
}

@Table({ timestamps: false, tableName: 'street' })
class Street extends Model<IStreet> {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column
    street_id: string;

    @Column
    location_id: string;

    @Column
    location_symbol: string;

    @Column
    street_name: string;

    @Column
    street_synonym: string;

    @Column
    street_symbol: string;

    @Column
    updated: Date;
}

Street.create({
    location_id: 'string',
    location_symbol: 'string',
    street_name: 'string',
    street_synonym: 'string',
    street_id: 'string',
    street_symbol: 'string',
    updated: new Date(),
});
```